# Sync data on App_Closing event

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, async-await

I have few clumps of data that needs to be sync'd. The app is a calendar where in dates are stored, along with few other information. So on app exit I need to sync the all dates to the server. The dates and other info are converted to Json format and sent.

I have used HttpWebRequest for getting the responses from the server and hence are a series of callbacks. The function SyncHistory is called in on the `Application_Closing`

What happens is that the I can see the execution moving to the SyncHistory but once the app is closed, it does not further call the other functions.

I need the app to sync data before it stops? I have tried await keyword, sometimes it calls the functions but some other times it does not?

Where should the code ideally be put. I dont want to sync data everytime the user enters data. Is there any other common exit points which runs even after the app is closed?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a great idea - you only have a maximum of 10s to complete `Application_Closing`, before the phone OS will shutdown your app forcibly. Once your app is closed (or shutdown forcibly) none of your code will run.

The nature of a mobile phone networking and cellular networks is that you can't rely on having sent all your data to a server in 10s. You'll have to think of an alternative strategy if you want this to be reliable.

And you haven't even consider the `Application_Deactivated` scenario where you get even less time to complete.

Comment: So the only way is to sync every time some value is modified?

Comment: Probably not the only way, but you'd need to upload frequently and often, deal with failure to upload, and that `Application_Deactivated` scenario where the network uploads are cancelled by the OS.